Unity UniWebView Android - Webview getting closed on switching Apps or Pressing Android's Home (minimize) button
Have implemented the Webview in Unity Android app to load a URL as follows:
    public void ActivateWebView(string link)
    {
        
        var webViewGameObject = new GameObject("UniWebView");
        webView = webViewGameObject.AddComponent<UniWebView>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(webViewGameObject);
        webView.Frame = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        webView.OnPageStarted += (UniWebView uni, string url) => 
        {
            print("webView created " + url);
        };
        
        webView.Load(link);
        webView.SetBackButtonEnabled(true);
        webView.Show();
    }

However, whenever I press the Android's Home button and then switch back to my App, the webview closes and moves back to the page from where Webview was launched. How to keep the webview session/context open until I specifically do not press Back button?
The official documentation (https://docs.uniwebview.com/api/) doesn't mention anything about how to keep the webview session open even after switching the App (or simply pressing Home button) on Android app.
